# prove or disprove-Hamilton circle

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V_G , E_G) $ and $H = (V_H , E_H) $ simple graphs and assume that G and H contains Hamilton circle and $V_G \cap V_H = \emptyset $.

and let $S = (V_S ,E_S)  $

$_ = _ × _ $ = {$(, ℎ)| ∈ _, ℎ ∈ _$}

$_$ = {$(_, ℎ_), (_, ℎ_)$ | {$_, _$} ∈ $_$   {$(ℎ_, ℎ_)$} ∈ $_$}

prove or disprove S contains a Hamilton circle.

I had tried to found for H and G triangle and there is a circle

Comment: Are you trying to evoke the Cartesian product of graphs ($G \square H$), or is this something different? If so, the set $E_S$ doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: indeed is the Cartesian product of the vertices set and Cartesian product of non order pairs.

Comment: Okay, so your problem is to show that the Cartesian product of two Hamiltonian graphs (say $G$ and $H$) is Hamiltonian. Observe first that it suffices to show the result when each of $G$ and $H$ are cycles (why?). Draw a small example; for instance draw out $C_3 \square C_4$, and try to find a Hamiltonian cycle in this graph. Generalise this for arbitrary $C_n \square C_m$. Note that you'll have to consider at least 2 different cases depending on parity.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time it exactly what I thought however to formalize it will be tough

Comment: If there's something specific you're stuck on, feel free to ask. I think my proof outline above will get you through the problem without any trouble so long as you're able to draw $C_3 \square C_4$ and see how to handle the difference between $n$ odd and $n$ even.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time i draw the circle and I found circle however I don't found a way to construct such circle explicitly

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't formally solved this problem, but I think my intuitive answer is correct. Given this, I can't 100% promise that this hint is useful.)

Hint: You can think of the graph $S$ as being "$G$, but where every vertex has been replaced with a mini copy of $H$". Is it possible to piece together the cycles that you can make inside each of the mini copies of $H$, into a cycle in $S$?

Comment: I thought about that. however to prove it formally it's tough. indiction doesn't work and is not easy to prove that at S will be Hamilton circle because you need more assumption about the circle.

Comment: Which other assumptions do you need? I think it will Just Work (tm).

Comment: that you can construct Hamilton circle by choosing for some path that combines the 2 circles